# How can i create row values using case statement

Tags: oracle

I am trying to create multiple 4-row values for a column using a case statement like this:

```
Case when time_zero = '00' then 'zero' case when time_zero ='01' then 'zeroOne' case when Day_of_Year ='Today' then '2day' when Day_of_Year ='yesterday' then 'yesterday end end as Ouput_column
```

This is for oracle 11g

```
Case when time_zero = '00' then 'zero' case when time_zero ='01' then 'zeroOne' case when Day_of_Year ='Today' then '2day' when Day_of_Year ='yesterday' then 'yesterday end end as Output_column
```

Expected results Output_column

```
zeroOne
2day
zero
yesterday
```

Comment: `case` expressions do not generate rows; they only affect values.  Sample data for the table you are using would help.

Comment: Some sample input data would be really helpful here.

Comment: perhaps my wording was not right, i am trying to get values from the two columns then create a new column called output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create the new column:

```
select *,
  case 
     when time_zero = '00' then 'zero'
     when time_zero ='01' then 'zeroOne'
     when Day_of_Year ='Today' then '2day' 
     when Day_of_Year ='yesterday' then 'yesterday' 
  end as Output_column
from tablename
```

The value of the column depends first on the value of the column `time_zero` and secondly on the value of the column `Day_of_Year`. 
It will be `null` if none of the conditions apply.